# Count non blank rows in a certain range/column Excel

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, row, nonblank

I want to count empty (or non-blank) rows in a given column (or range). 
Example: I have a column which is spaning over 4 cells width, and each cell has either a single ''x'' or is empty. There is up to 100 rows under this column. Here's a picture to clarify:

[image: Snip of the excel sheet]

Answer (score 5):

The `COUNTA()` function will do that for you. For example:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A100)
```

Will return the number of non-blank cells in the range **A1:A100**

Comment: Since the column in which I want to look is 4 cells wide, this formula counts all the ''x'' in the range I specified (B2:E9)... This is not what I want. I want to count non blank rows.

Comment: In your case, what is the difference between a **non-blank** cell and a cell with "x" in?

Comment: It's the same thing I just wanted to generalise.

Comment: He wants non-blank rows, not cells

Answer (score 4):

You can use array formula. For example, to count the first 10 rows starting from row 2.

```
=SUM((COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(B2,ROW(1:10)-1,0,1,4))=4)*1)
```

[image]

To count the first 100 rows:

```
=SUM((COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(B2,ROW(1:100)-1,0,1,4))=4)*1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a new column to get the number of blank cells in each row, then count the number of row in this column which are equal to 4.

Or, more simply, write `=QUOTIENT(COUNTBLANK(B2:E2);4)` in F2, pull the cell down, then write `=SUM(F2:F101)` in G2.

If there is exactly 4 blank cell in a row, the F cell will have a value of 1 and the sum will just add all of these 1 to get the number of empty rows.