# How to count the number of non empty columns without giving a range?

Tags: excel, count, row, nonblank

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618868/count-non-blank-rows-in-a-certain-range-column-excel) question is asked how to count the number of non-empty rows for a given range (e.g., `A1:A100`).

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39619052/4480180) answer, `COUNTA` is used as solution. However, is there a solution without specifying the range?

Comment: So how would you define the area to count over? Every method of counting i can think of will need a search space defined.

Comment: I have just included an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618868/count-non-blank-rows-in-a-certain-range-column-excel/39619052#39619052. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean with dynamic range like:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)
```