# EXCEL count non-empty rows in non-contiguous range

Tags: excel, count, is-empty

I'm trying to count how many non-empty row I have in a range that is non-contiguous. I know it's easy to do if I create additional column that checks if a row is empty and then count that, but I'd like to do all that in a single cell.
Here's an example table:
[image]

So here my ranges would be "A1:C10" ; "E1:F10" ; "H1:H10" and I want to count the rows that are empty in these ranges. (So in this case the answer would be 2: rows "5" and "8") Note that there might be data in column "D" and "G" that I need to disregard in the evaluation. Also in the real data I have a lot of rows, but the number of ranges (columns)that is need to evaluate at a time are not the much so it is acceptable to enter the ranges in the formula by hand.

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618868/count-non-blank-rows-in-a-certain-range-column-excel) and tried the formula in the last answer, but as far as I know I can't use non-contiguous range with COUNTBLANK, so I couldn't modify to work for me.

I tried this (entering as array formula) but it didn't work:

```
=SUM(IF(AND((COUNTA(OFFSET(E5,ROW(1:13)-1,0,1,4))=0),(COUNTA(OFFSET(I5,ROW(1:13)-1,0,1,1))=0), (COUNTA(OFFSET(C5,ROW(1:13)-1,0,1,))=0)),0,1))
```

Does anybody know a good formula or method for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use MMULT as it is not volatile like OFFSET.

```
=SUM(--(MMULT((A2:H11<>"")*(COLUMN(A2:H11)<>4)*(COLUMN(A2:H11)<>7),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A2:H11)^0))=0))
```

Depending on one's version of Excel it may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Nice! It works with the example, but what if I have more that one "unnecessary" column between two ranges? Do I need to add more `*(COLUMN(A2:H11)<>4)` with the correct col index to exclude all?
Could you perhaps also explain a little how it works, so it'd be easier to customize it?